# Using updateOrCreate for multiple data insert in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, orm, eloquent

I have used the following **insert array** to insert multiple entries in **Laravel** `Eloquent ORM`

```
$i = 0;
foreach($exerciseValArray as $kkey=>$exerciseValue){
    if($exerciseValue['exercise'] =='' || $exerciseValue['section_type'] == ''){
        return Response::JSON(array('errors'=>array('Error in workout exercise section')));
    }   
    $exerciseData = explode(',',$exerciseValue['exercise']);
    foreach($exerciseData as $exerciseid){
        $insertArray[$i]['fk_workouts_id'] = $id;
        $insertArray[$i]['fk_users_id']    = $userId;
        $insertArray[$i]['fk_exercises_id']= $exerciseid;
        $insertArray[$i]['section']        = $exerciseValue['section_type'];
        $insertArray[$i]['status']         = 1;
        $insertArray[$i]['item_index']     = $index+$kkey+1;
        $insertArray[$i]['updated_at']     =  $workoutDetails['updated_at'];
        $i++;
    }
}
WorkoutExercise::insert($insertArray);
```

The above code works fine and inserts the data array in to the database.

I have learnt the usage of `Model::updateOrCreate` and used it in some of my modules successfully (i.e)

```
Model::updateOrCreate($attributes = array('key' => 'value'), $values = array('key' => 'value'));
```

My question is how to edit the above insert snippet so that I could use `Model::updateOrCreate` in it. My `$attributes` fields are 'fk_workouts_id','fk_users_id','fk_exercises_id' and the rest in the `$values` to be changed.

I have no idea how to implement this. Pls help...

Comment: Eloquent can't insert/update multiple rows, you need to process them one by one. The `insert` method is in fact `Query\Builder`s and it doesn't use Eloquent features at all (eg. timestamps and so on).

Comment: is there any other way in `Eloquent` or `Query\Builder` that I could create entry or update if data presence @JarekTkaczyk . Because I need to updateOrCreate nearly 20-50 data is it a good practice to do it one by one??

Comment: Good practice in what way? You can either write 3 lines of code and let Eloquent do the job, or say 13 lines of code, where you do the job. Eloquent has `firstOrNew` method, which is the way to go.

Comment: Jarek Tkaczyk already gave you the answer and there's no way around it. What are you looking for? (since you added a bounty)

Answer (score 10):

You can try like,

**First Way**

```
 $user = User::firstOrNew(array('name' => 'satish'));
 $user->field = 'value';
 $user->save();
```

It will check for user `name=satish` if found then return it. If not found then create new and return. Then you can set field values.

Check this link.
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#insert-update-delete

**Second Way**
Mannually Check record is exists.

```
 $arr=array('field'=>"value");
 $row = User::find($id);
  if ($row === null) {
       //Insert your record 

  } else {
       //update your record
  }
```

---

**UPDATED**

You can also use `updateOrCreate` - update an existing model or create a new model if none exists. `updateOrCreate` persists the model, so there's no need to call  `save()`.

Example-

```
// If there's a flight from Oakland to San Diego, set the price to $99.
// If no matching model exists, create one.
$flight = App\Flight::updateOrCreate(
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego'],
    ['price' => 99]
);
```

Comment: How would you use updateOrCreate for updating or creating multiple rows of data, but each row you are updating is updating different columns in the DB?

Comment: put the updateOrCreate inside of the loop

Answer (score 1):

I think you are working with the customized framework of laravel so you have UpdateOrCreate method because laravel not provides such methods if my assumption is true than below written code may b useful for your application

```
foreach($exerciseValArray as $kkey=>$exerciseValue){

  if($exerciseValue['exercise'] =='' || $exerciseValue['section_type'] == ''){
     return Response::JSON(array('errors'=>array('Error in workout exercise section')));
  }   
  $exerciseData = explode(',',$exerciseValue['exercise']);
  $attr_array = array('fk_workouts_id','fk_users_id','fk_exercises_id','section','status','item_index','updated_at');

  foreach($exerciseData as $exerciseid){

      $val_array = array($userId,$exerciseid,$exerciseValue['section_type'],1,$item_index,$workoutDetails['updated_at']);
      WorkoutExercise::updateOrCreate($attr_array,$val_array);
  }
}
```

But if you are not using such kind of customized framework than please try with the below code it may work fine

```
foreach($exerciseValArray as $kkey=>$exerciseValue){

  if($exerciseValue['exercise'] =='' || $exerciseValue['section_type'] == ''){
    return Response::JSON(array('errors'=>array('Error in workout exercise section')));
  }   
  $exerciseData = explode(',',$exerciseValue['exercise']);

  foreach($exerciseData as $exerciseid){

    $item_index = $index+$kkey+1;

    // Retrieve the record by the fk_workouts_id, or create it if it doesn't exist...
    $exercise = WorkoutExercise::firstOrCreate($attributes = array('fk_workouts_id' => $id));

    /* assign the values of other fields to store in database table*/
    $exercise->fk_users_id      = $userId;
    $exercise->fk_exercises_id  = $exerciseid;
    $exercise->section          = $exerciseValue['section_type'];
    $exercise->status           = 1;
    $exercise->item_index       = $item_index;
    $exercise->updated_at       = $workoutDetails['updated_at'];
    $exercise->save(); // update the record
  }
}
```

good luck...:)

Comment: the queries will be executed throughout the `foreach` right?? is there a way to minimize the queries??

Comment: I don't think so we will have the solution for this requirements. But if I found that then will surely revert back to you....